# Sorting a simple array of test scores in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to learn java by myself. I know this is probably a really easy question for most of you, but I am confused. So lets say I have a list of scores of people, say a, b, c, d who received 4, 2, 3 and 1 in a test.
So I have:

```
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String[] names = { "a","b","c","d" };
        int[] times = { 4,2,3,1};
```

How do I write the code in order to find the highest score and the second highest score?

Thanks load in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to sort it, as per title, or get 2 highest scores?

Comment: Well, if you spend just a few minutes searching the Java API documentation you will happen upon SortedMap.  Or, if you Google "sort algorithm", you will find the Wikipedia page on the topic, with descriptions of several common sort algorithms.  Searching further you will find stuff like Java's Array.sort.  Dig a little.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29).

```
{
    Arrays.sort(times);
    System.out.println(times[times.length-1]);
    System.out.println(times[times.length-2]);
}
```

[View a live code demo.](http://ideone.com/m7Zatg)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a very simple technique [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for sorting your array in descending order

Something like,

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<array.length-1-i; j++) {
        if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1])>0) {
            t= array[j];
            array[j] = array[j+1];
            array[j+1] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[image]

**EDIT**

For `Lambda Expression` I would suggest you to first go through [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and first *try it your self*. If you face any problem then let us know here.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but it's better to use a native library method, given the question matter implies a learning programmer. :)

Comment: @Unihedron Yes. That's why I wrote "very simple technique"

Comment: @GPRathour I posted my answer how you like it? I think it makes you happy lol

Answer (score 0):

use [the Array.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) method on your array, and then use the indexes. When it is sorted this way it is in ascending order.

```
Arrays.sort(times);
int highest = times[times.length-1]; // arrays start at index 0, so "-1"
int secondhighest = times[times.length-2];
```

Comment: Your first line will fail to compile because `Arrays.sort(int[])` is of return type `void`.

Comment: I see, sort rearranges `times`, so `times` is still `times` just sorted. no need to save `times` as another variable!

Comment: Downvote retracted but unfortunately this is now (almost) a duplicate of my answer. Glad we're both learning.

Answer (score 0):

How to accomplish this in `Java 8`

Code:

```
    Integer[] numbers = {2,4,3,1,5,6,8,7};
    List<Integer> N = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    System.out.print("the list ");
    N.forEach((i)->System.out.print(i + " "));
    System.out.println();
    Comparator<Integer> byThis = (i, j) -> Integer.compare(
         i,j);
    System.out.print("the ordered list ");
    N.stream().sorted(byThis).forEach(i->System.out.print(i+" "));
    System.out.println("");

    String[] names = {"c", "b", "a", "d"};
    for(String st: names) System.out.print(st + " " );
    System.out.println(); 
    List<String> S = Arrays.asList(names);
    S.stream().sorted().forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));

   System.out.println("\n The Max Number is " + N.stream().max(byThis).get());
```

Output:

```
the list 2 4 3 1 5 6 8 7 
the ordered list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

the list c b a d 
the ordered list a b c d

The Max Number is 8
```

Source:

http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/

http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/comparator-tutorial.php